# Will my adha salat be in order if I skip 3 qaza salat and pray it later?

Tags: salat, salat-qada

Suppose I have missed 2 fajr and an asr salat and now they are qaza. Now I perform my magrib salat but do not  pray any qaza salat. Then I pray 2 fajr qaza salat before starting isha salat. And I perform the asr qaza salat after finishing my Fajr salat the next day.

Now will my magrib,isha and fajr salat be accepted?

Answer (score -2):

It is important that you know a few important things...

> So woe to those who pray, [But] who are heedless of their prayer... (Qur'an 107:4-5)
>
> Indeed, those who fear their Lord unseen will have forgiveness and great reward. (Qur'an 67:12)
>
> Then exalt [Him] with praise of your Lord and ask forgiveness of Him. Indeed, He is ever Accepting of repentance. (Qur'an 110:3)

If you've prayed them in that order in unavoidable condition, then let's hope that Allah will accept your prayers, he it is who hears what we say. There's no one here who can confirm whether they've been accepted or not...

May the creator guide us all.